# Need to implement push notification for google docs update in my own app

Tags: android, push-notification, push, google-docs, google-docs-api

Suppose I share my document with someone and if he/she modifies something then I want to get a push notification for that in my own app just like google docs gets it. Is it possible via C2DM? if yes then how?

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow community! If you find a particular answer helpful, please upvote it. If a particular response is the correct answer to your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible via C2DM. Please look at the documentation on [Sending a Message](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/#push-process) for details.